# Not possible to loop over PHFetchResult with ForEach

Tags: swift, xcode, swiftui, photokit

I'm currently working on a photos app for iOS / macOS and i'm struggeling with PhotoKit.

I did create a class where i manage all my PhotoKit requests.

```
class PhotosAPI: ObservableObject {

@Published var all = PHFetchResult<PHAsset>()
@Published var allAlbums = PHFetchResult<PHAssetCollection>()
@Published var allSmartAlbums = PHFetchResult<PHAssetCollection>()

// Functions to get the Collections / Assets

}
```

This part is working so far but now i'm struggeling with showing those data in my View.

In my View i would like to present all Assets in a List / Grid

```
struct ShowImages: View {

    @ObservedObject var photos = PhotosAPI()

    var body: some View {
        List(photos.all, id: \.self) { item in
            Text("\(item)")
        }
    }
}
```

But i do get an error "Initializer 'init(_:id:rowContent:)' requires that 'PHFetchResult' conform to 'RandomAccessCollection'" and i did try all day today to fix this but i wasn't successful and i couldn't find anything useful in google.

Does anyone have an idea how i can get PHFetchResults to loop over them?

At the end i was able to show the pictures with below code. But this looks like very bad code to me. I would prefer to loop directly over the PHFetchResult. Does anyone know how i can get this done?

```
ForEach(0..<photos.all.count) { index in
    Text("\(photos.all.object(at: index).localIdentifier)")
}
```

Comment: You can either try to make `PHFetchResult` conform to `RandomAccessCollection` or store arrays of `PHAsset` instead of `PHFetchResults`. If you're having performance issues you can use one of the new lazy views in iOS 14 or paginate the photos.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can implement `RandomAccessCollection` for `PHFetchResult` or create wrapper that conforms `RandomAccessCollection`.

```
struct PHFetchResultCollection: RandomAccessCollection, Equatable {

    typealias Element = PHAsset
    typealias Index = Int

    let fetchResult: PHFetchResult<PHAsset>

    var endIndex: Int { fetchResult.count }
    var startIndex: Int { 0 }

    subscript(position: Int) -> PHAsset {
        fetchResult.object(at: fetchResult.count - position - 1)
    }
}
```

Then you will be able to use `PHFetchResultCollection` with `ForEach`

```
let collection = PHFetchResultCollection(fetchResult: fetchResult)

var body: some View  {
    ForEach(collection, id: \.localIdentifier) {
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: if some one need one for PHAssetCollection same code as above would work just replace the PHAsset with PHAssetCollection, make a seperate PHFetchResultAssetCollection struct would do the job.

Answer (score 2):

You can enumerate the items of the fetched results object with the `enumerate` methods, such as this one:

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/photokit/phfetchresult/1620999-enumerateobjects

Comment: If it makes you feel any better, I regard the fact that you can't use `for...in` as a bug. It's caused by the fact that this is a generic object.

Comment: It looks like PhotoKit is not working well together with SwiftUI. I'm currently trying the approach to enumerate over the fetch result and write all localIdentifier into one Array of Strings and then in the view looping over the localIdentifier. But this have some performance issues especially on large photo libraries

Comment: That may well be, but I believe the actual question was how to loop over a fetch result.